# I want to make an installer for my application

Tags: c, gtk, installation

I finished creating my application I used GTK and language C in Code::Blocks , What I'm trying to do now is to make an installer for the application for Linux; so that when I give it to someone He install it and it'll work on his computer .

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: for Linux it would be great if it could do Linux and Windows

Comment: @lurker so is there a way for Linux because i just remembered that the application is not compatible with windows

Comment: I would start with creating an `rpm` package. There's lots of online document describing how that's done.

Comment: the application is based on GTK so how can i include that in the installer and is it really needed

Comment: Sorry, I haven't built an `rpm` installer with GTK included before. Maybe someone else can chime in. Perhaps [this link](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Deploying_Your_Application) will assist.

Comment: Just one more question for the code source what should i do with those stuff adding to that the executable that code:blocks make is not working

Answer (score 2):

Linux doesn't have the same concept of an installer that Windows has. There are three ways to distribute an application, and sometime more than one is used at once:

1. Distribute the source of your program in a normal archive and have the user build it
2. Distribute the binary of your program in a normal archive and have the user run it
3. Create a *package* containing your program's binaries and have the user install that

The last option is distribution-specific. `rpm`, which user @lurker mentioned above, is only used by a number of distributions, the primary one(s) being Red Hat/Fedora. There is also `deb`, which is for both Debian and Ubuntu, as well as one for SUSE and Arch, and possibly many more. Googling will show you how to make all of these, or in some cases, integrate the making of the package into your build process.

Systems with package managers also provide dependency management for you. Each `rpm` and `deb` for a GTK+ 2 or GTK+ 3 program say that GTK+ 2 or GTK+ 3 is a dependency. (The package name for GTK+ 2 or GTK+ 3 is the distro-specific part). In general, you don't want to bundle GTK+ or other dependencies with your program (unless those dependencies are statically linked in; for GTK+ this is definitely **not** the case). Even if you decide not to use packages and just provide binaries and/or source in an archive file, you still don't want to actually include the dependencies for this reason.

You may find that some commercial or non-open-source Linux software does come with an installer program. I would advise against following the crowd here, but if you feel you have no other option then I can't name any programs for making this off the top of my head.

Comment: how can i do the second one if i might ask ?

Comment: You simply distribute the executable, optionally put into an archive (zip, tar, etc.). If there are other files that you depend on, this will get trickier...

Comment: but the problem is that the executable doesn't work when i double click it and also what do you mean by files i depend on do you mean like file.txt and other images i use in the application

Comment: The executable needs to have execute permissions (zip won't preserve that, but tar will). Yes, I mean image files accessed externally.

Comment: how can i change permission for executable because when i double click it nothing happens like i didn't clicked it nothing shows up

Comment: even when i changed the permission to executable it didn't work